# Change HTML overflow

Tags: css, overflow

I am having a hard time changing something I image is in fact very simple. On the left side you can see my code. On the right side you can see the inspected code on the broswer.

What I need is to change the "overflow: hidden;" to "overglof: scroll;". I have already created it on the html { tag but it still appears the same on the inspector.

Any ideas? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code.

```
html{
    overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: well. actually it solved the issue! :) although the tag still appears as hidden on the inspector, the scroll is already working. thanks!!